# show only ground overlays map android?

Tags: android, google-maps

hello I'm implementing ground overlay in android. Now i want to clear background arround Ground overlay or show only Ground Overlay.

**default**
[image]

**now I want**
[image]

so how the code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595313/android-google-maps-groundoverlay

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar. Did you manage to hide everything else except the ground overlay?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

GoogleMap MapType = MAP_TYPE_NONE

Comment: could you elaborate more on the line of code you presented and add some verbal explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old Thread but it might help someone. Try using a MapStyle JSON string like the one below.

> "[{\"featureType\": \"administrative\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"off\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"landscape\",\"elementType\": \"geometry.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#e0fbc6\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"poi\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"off\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"poi\",\"elementType\": \"labels.icon\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"off\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"poi\",\"elementType\": \"labels.text\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"off\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"road\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"off\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"transit\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"off\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"water\",\"elementType\": \"labels.text\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"off\"}]}]"

Swift:

```
do {
     // Set the map style by passing a valid JSON string.
     mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(jsonString: mapStyleString)
} catch {
     NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
}
```

Android:

```
map.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions(JSON_STYLE_MAP)
```

Creating a Style:
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com